# Printing \toccontents and \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to print both `\toccontents` and `\tableofcontents` (in two separate parts of my document). However, printing the first stops the second from being printed. I have seen a number of related questions, but none have been able to solve it for me.

I am using class `report` (with `notitlepage`). I'm also using `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
        \sffamily
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
        {\Large \bfseries Table of Contents}\par
        \toccontents
        \normalfont
    \end{minipage}}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\chapter{Section}

words

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@starttoc` closes the `.toc` file and rewrites it,so after using `\@starttoc`, the `.toc` file is empty until the next run.

Comment: if you use `\usepackage{etoc}` you can type `\tableofcontents` anytime anywhere

Comment: @touhami -- that doesn't give the spacing and header that I want. I'm even putting it inside a minipage. I thought this wouldn't make a difference, and wanted the MWE to be *minimal*, but I'll include it as it may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `etoc`. We need to use `\etocsettocstyle`
to give the style (spacing and header)

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand{\mytableofcontents}{%
{\etocsettocstyle{\centering\begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}\sffamily
{\Large \bfseries \contentsname\par}}{\end{minipage}\par}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{0}
\tableofcontents}}

\begin{document}

\mytableofcontents

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Foo}
\section{Foo bar}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Bla}
\section{Bla bla}

words

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `memoir` class (a superset of the `report` (and `book`) class) you can have multiple ToCs in one document. Each ToC can have a different configuration if desired. The user manual (`> texdoc memoir`) has both a short and a full ToC with very different styles and section *9.2.5 Example: Multiple contents* documents the code for doing this.

Comment: By "a superset" do you mean that anything I can do in `report` can be done in `memoir` (and the same for `book`)?

Comment: @SamT: superset like frankensteins monster is a superset of all the people it got its body parts from. Inside `memoir` a lot of functionality is integrated which is usually done by packages, as the class author didn't liked package clashes. It's powerful but from a software module perspective its just terrible.

Comment: Ok, thanks. @touhami has given a solution below using `report`, which is what I've been using, and it's for an essay due in ~4days, so I think I'm going to stick with 'minimal changes'. Thanks for explaining though! :)